# How can I configure PhpStorm so it recognizes javascript with embedded php

Tags: phpstorm

In my framework I can have javascript files with embedded php.

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(<?php echo $message ?>);
});
```

How can I let PhpStorm detect the right languages so both javascript and php get correct syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE 2023-04-24**

As PhpStorm v9 (which is year 2015 or so), the IDE automatically detects the outer language if double file extension is used (the actual ticket: [WI-24237](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24237)).

So if your file is named `some.js.php` then it will automatically use JavaScript with PHP and there is no need for steps #2 and #3.

---

Three steps:

1. Give such a file custom (e.g. `*.phpjs`) or complex (`*.js.php` or `*.php.js`) file extension.
2. If the file extension does NOT end in `.php` then assign such a pattern to **PHP** file type in `Settings/Preferences | File Types`. This is needed so the file is treated as PHP (otherwise you will have no PHP syntax highlighting).

   - If you do not want to give it such custom extension (for whatever reasons you may have there) then you'll have to assign full file name as a pattern (which can cause issues/confusion if you have another file with the same file name in another folder, even in another project).
   - **Please note** -- this is an an IDE-wide setting so it will affect all projects and therefore custom/complex extension is the best and *safe* way to go (since it's more universal).
3. `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages` -- locate your file there and assign **JavaScript** to it (or whole folder, if all files in it will be treated similarly) -- this will set JavaScript as primary (outer) language instead of default HTML.

[image]
*(PHP & JavaScript syntax colors + showing a tooltip for JavaScript's `alert()` function in a file named `some.js.php`)*